# Frontend ajax POST call can't login to Django

Tags: ajax, django, authentication, registration, tastypie

I've spent several days to no avail and was wondering if anyone could help me? I am trying to use Django as a backend only with the ultimate goal of porting to a mobile application. I have a form and ajax call in the front end to a url/view in Django (REST API as well if that is relevant), but for some reason that I don't understand the call won't go through to log me in.

Relevant applications:

- Django-Userena
- Tastypie

Could anyone advise me in the right direction? Below is the code and thank you!

index.html

`<script>`

`$(document).ready(function(){`

```
`//login test`

`$('#login').submit(function(){`

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signin/',
        type: 'POST',
        //data: loginString,
        data: $('#login').serialize(),
        success: function() {
            alert('Test');
            $('#datadisplay').append("<h2>It worked</h2>");
        },  
        error: function(errorThrown){
            alert('Error');
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});

});

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="datadisplay"></div>
<input type="submit" id="getdata" value="Submit">

<div id="loginform">
 <form name="login" id="login" action="">
     <fieldset>
        <label for="id_identification">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="identification" id="id_identification" size="30" value="" />
        <br/>

        <label for="id_password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" size="30" value="" />
        <br/>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="loginbutton" value="Login" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

api.py

`class UserResource(ModelResource):`

```
   class Meta:
       queryset = User.objects.all()
       resource_name = 'user'
       include_resource_uri = False
       allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']


def override_urls(self):
    return [url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/signin%s$" %
    (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
    self.wrap_view('signin'), name="api_signin"),
    ]

def signin(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])

    data = self.deserialize(request, request.raw_post_data, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))

    username = data.get('username', '')
    password = data.get('password', '')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return self.create_response(request, {
            'success': True
            })
        else:
            return self.create_response(request, {
            'success': False,
            'reason': 'disabled',
            }, HttpForbidden )
    else:
        return self.create_response(request, {
        'success': False,
        'reason': 'incorrect',
        }, HttpUnauthorized )
```

Comment: Are you using the CSRF framework? Or rather, did you disable it in settings.py, seeing as you are not passing the CSRF token in your POST call? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/ What is your Javascript console printing? What does the network inspector say about the data returned by the AJAX call?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my code. How would I pass csrf token through ajax or is is django side only? Typically it just cancels the POST request in error before it can even give a xxx number error. Times when it does go through it'll print me an error of [object object]

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/accounts/signin/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}',
        //other variables
    },
    success: function() {
        alert('Test');
        $('#datadisplay').append("<h2>It worked</h2>");
    },  
    error: function(errorThrown){
        alert('Error');
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```